# Install full Nvidia 1060ti Drivers

Tags: graphic-drivers

Hi guys do you know how can I install  the complete drivers fir my 1060ti Nvidia, is integrated in my laptop. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the graphics-drivers ppa.

You will have to run the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

That will enable you to add ppa's to your repositories. After that you need to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

After running the second command (or rebooting/waiting for the system to update repositories by itself), new drivers will appear in the AppCenter. You can install them there, or alternatively, you can install via terminal.

To find out **which driver** is the **correct one,** go to https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk and select your graphics card. E.g. for Titan X (Pascal) it will show you (at time of this writing) the 418 series driver (version 418.56). Generaly you can obtain best results with the version shown. **Do not download** the driver from there, but rather install the appropriate version from the AppCenter, or in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418
```

Reboot your computer, and you should be able to run the NVIDIA X Server Settings app, and your card should appear there correctly...

*Note:* You can try to install the driver from the Nvidia site, but you can also run into all sort of problems with that and if you are capable to get it working that way, you probably would not ask such questions here. You can also experiment with other driver versions, but you should make sure the relevant driver will support your card. With 1060Ti you can also try the newest 430 series, but that driver is still under development, so it may contain bugs and not be that stable - but on the other hand you may get better performance out of it... The best way how to test various drivers is to first uninstall the previous one and then install the new one. You should not have multiple driver versions installed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try (Version:   367.44 Release Date:    2016.8.23 )
for the following GPUs:

TITAN X (Pascal)
GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
GeForce GTX 1060 3GB

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/106780/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Did you try In the: Appcenter 
Installed / Drivers / nvidia-driver-390
(390.48) today

Comment: Yes but it has a glitch, If I installed the hdmi port stop woking