# Live USB only displays on half the screen - installation fails

Tags: system-installation, display, grub, graphics

I'm trying to install elementary on a brand new HP Envy laptop, with a 10th gen Intel processor and a 1650 Ti GPU.

When booting to the live USB, only half of the display renders properly. The desktop gets squished into half the screen, with the bottom half failing to display. The installation then fails on grub-install.

I've updated the BIOS, re-downloaded the ISO, and re-flashed my USB drive. I've also disabled secure boot. These have not fixed the issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The issue must be related to the graphics drivers (being a brand new computer, the driver support is usually lacking). What's the error message you get when you try to install elementary?

Comment: I managed to get Pop OS installed, I believe the grub issue was just my mistake with partitioning. The install was successful but I still have that "half screen" problem that appears to be graphics related. I switched to the integrated graphics in place of the GPU, but it still looks the same.

Comment: Execute `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to obtain the latest graphics drivers for your system.

Comment: I ran that, latest drivers installed, still the same screen problem. Considering the display looks the same when using the NVIDIA chip as when using the CPU's integrated graphics, is it possible my issue is a problem with some display driver rather than GPU driver?

Comment: I don't think there's another display driver besides the GPU. You have the same problem with both graphics cards because only one graphic card is hardwired to the display. The other graphics card is offloading work from the first one (to increase performance). You can read a better explanation [here](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/nouveau/Optimus/) .

Regarding your card, you may need to install beta drivers. For what I've seen, your card has been added last year so it may take a while to receive good support.

Comment: To install beta drivers follow the first answer of [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16335/install-full-nvidia-1060ti-drivers) . But please, backup any important info beforehand, you are getting into uncharted territory!

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I'm fine with waiting for the drivers to get better support. It took a while for my desktop's AMD 5700XT to get support on a lot of distros.

Comment: I'll try out installing the beta drivers, otherwise the waiting game will continue. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hope you are staying safe. I noticed that you posted a question on the HP forum where they basically told you to pay to fix the problem they caused. I'm going through the same issue with my recently purchased HP laptop. There is a Linux forum where I posted my issue and the members there are trying to sort it out for me. I wanted to reach out to see if you had found a solution to your monitor problem that I'm also going through. Thanks

Comment: @nmssis I recently tried again and had some success. A user I had been talking with on Reddit told me he was able to install Linux Mint Mate and didn't have the "squished screen" issue anymore. I tried that and was also successful.

I then tried installing the latest elementary OS 5.1 build. The live USB installer still had the same issue, but after installing the OS I was able to install all available updates, rebooted, and things displayed properly! 

I do still have a weird "flicker" or glitch every minute or so, but at least it displays correctly most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The live USB still displays with the same "squished screen" problem. However after installing the OS and running all the updates, it displays properly (only using the nouveau driver).

I then installed the latest proprietary NVIDIA driver (nvidia-video-460) which also displays properly, without the "squished" screen.

I also installed Linux Mint MATE 20.1 which displays correctly before updating any software. I'm not sure whether an update to kernel or the nouveau driver was responsible for fixing this mess.

*Note that there's still some driver issues with this laptop. The screen "flickers" or "glitches" about every minute, or more often. While this can be annoying, it's at least now useable.*

Answer (score 0):

TRY ubuntu 20.04 and turn on internet while installing ubuntu, it will install all the drivers and best kernel suited to your need

Comment: No change. Same display issue regardless of distro: Ubuntu, elementary, Pop!, and Manjaro all have this same problem on my machine. Even booting into an Arch USB, only half the screen is used for the terminal.

Comment: https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/display.html?m=1

Comment: Try these some solutions might some work most probably nvidia resolution